# expect script not matching in bash

Tags: expect

I have function who is calling expect , but expect is not matching second line, it is matching first match match, I tried all sort of thinks, please help

```
 function login_ssh_user {
    logger $FUNCNAME "start"
    if [ -z "${LDAPPWD}" ]; then
                            get_ldap_pwd
    fi

    echo "\n ${LDAPUSR} \n\n"
    echo "\n ${LDAPPWD} \n"
    echo "\n ${SOESYS}  \n"
    export U1="${LDAPUSR}"
    export S1="${SOESYS}"
    export P1="${LDAPPWD}"
    expect << EOF
            spawn ssh "$U1@$S1";
            expect "password:" { send $P1\r }
            expect  "$ " { send_user "Login Success ... PASS\n"; send exit\r }
            **expect  "denied" { send_user "Login Failure ... Fail\n";** send "^C" }
EOF
    logger $FUNCNAME "end"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code indicates you expect to see the password prompt, then you expect to see a shell prompt, then you expect to see Denied. Clearly you will *either* see the prompt *or* the denied message:

```
function login_ssh_user {
    #...
    export U1="${LDAPUSR}"
    export S1="${SOESYS}"
    export P1="${LDAPPWD}"
    expect << 'EOF'
            spawn ssh $env(U1)@$env(S1)
            expect "password:" { send $env(P1)\r }
            expect  {
                "$ "    { send_user "Login Success ... PASS\n"; send exit\r }
                denied" { send_user "Login Failure ... Fail\n"; send \x03 }
            }
EOF
    logger $FUNCNAME "end"
}
```

Notes:

- I've quoted the EOF in the redirection. That effectively single quotes the whole expect script body
- you export your variables, so expect can fetch them out of the `env` array
- both the shell prompt and "denied" are branches in a single expect command. Whichever one expect sees first will "win".
- Ctrl+C is \x03

Comment: Thanks Glenn, whole issue was 'EOF', otherwise I tried every option, really appreciated